# Stata Regular expressions extracting numerical values

Tags: stata

I have some data that looks like this

```
var1
h 01 .00 .0 abc
d 1.0 .0 14.0abc
1,0.0 0.0 .0abc
```

It should be noted that the last three alpha values are the same, and I am hoping to extract all the numerical values within the string. The code that I'm using look like this

```
gen x1=regexs(1) if regexm(var1,"([0-9]+) [ ]*(abc)*$")
```

However, this code only extracts the numbers before the *abc* term and stops after a space or a *.*. For example, only 0 before *abc* is extracted from the first term. I was wondering whether there is a way to handle this and extract all the numerical values before the alpha characters.

Comment: Can you please show exactly how the resulting variable is supposed to look like? Is that a comma in your last observation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Roberto Ferrer points out, your question isn't very clear, but here is an example using `moss` from SSC:

```
. clear 

. input str16 var1

                var1
1. "h 01 .00 .0 abc"
2. "d 1.0 .0 14.0abc"
3. "1,0.0 0.0 .0abc"
4. end 

. moss var1, regex match("([0-9]+\.*[0-9]*|\.[0-9]+)") 

. l _match*

   +---------------------------------------+
   | _match1   _match2   _match3   _match4 |
   |---------------------------------------|
1. |      01       .00        .0           |
2. |     1.0        .0      14.0           |
3. |       1       0.0       0.0        .0 |
   +---------------------------------------+
```